# Hive Extract Data in a Array

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I need to extract the 5th value from data string array in Hive,

```
arr = ("abc", "123-4567", "10", "ax", "cdpp asd", "00", "q", "na", "avail", "n", "n", "na")
```

How can I extract `"cdpp asd"` ie 5th value.

We can use `SUBSTR`, and `INSTR` but is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: how are you supposed to extract a value from array by using `substr` or `instr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your array is in string column then you can remove brackets and double quotes using `regexp_replace` and split resulted string to get an array using `split()`:

```
 select split(regexp_replace('("abc", "123-4567", "10", "ax",   "cdpp asd", "00", "q", "na", "avail", "n", "n",   "na")','^\\(|\\)$|"',''),', *')[4];
OK
cdpp asd
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = ("abc", "123-4567", "10", "ax", "cdpp asd", "00", "q", "na", "avail", "n", "n", "na")

Select arr[4] from tablename;
```

Output:

```
cdpp asd
```

Answer (score 0):

1、Maybe you can try to write a `UDF` to cast this string to an Array `arr`, then you can use arr[4] to visit the 5th value;

2、Or you can use the following way to get the 5th value:

```
    select tf.* from (
        select regexp_replace('("abc", "123-4567", "10", "ax", "cdpp asd", "00", "q", "na", "avail", "n", "n", "na")','\\(|\\)|"','') as str
    ) t lateral view posexplode(split(str,', ')) tf as pos,val
    where tf.pos = 4;
```

Note: this way require the array string has no brackets.